# Kubernetes Backend Pods Endpoints are BLANK

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, endpoint, azure-aks

I have deployed a node js Application on K8 1.16 version.I notice that post deployment the backend pods are not registering the end points , The back end pods thus keep restarting and go into CrashLoopBackOff.

```
 kubectl describe svc
Name:              backend-xx-backend-svc
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          chart=backend-xx-backend,tier=backend
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                192.168.246.12
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        8800/TCP
Endpoints:
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Any suggestions as to why the backend pod end points are blank.

Comment: If the Pod goes in CrashLoopBackOff, can you describe them, and check the logs with kubectl logs command?

Comment: Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From                                        Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----                                        -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  13s (x1187 over 3h19m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-33316079-vmss000002  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.39.67.76:8800/api/health: dial tcp 10.39.67.76:8800: connect: connection refused   - This is what I see on describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per result of describe command mentioned in the comment, it looks like Readiness probe is failing. Unless a pod is in Ready state, k8s won't forward traffic to that pod; so may be that's why end point in the Service object is blank as none of the pod is in Ready state. Check why Readiness probe i.e. Get 10.39.67.76:8800/api/health is failing. If your app takes time at the start then increase initialDelaySeconds or failureThreshold of Readiness Probe configuration.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , also any pointers on the best way to debug the failing health API calls it would help as I am a newbee to K8s :)

Comment: First try with increasing initialDelaySeconds which means probe will start after some time (time NodeJS app (server) takes to come up). Check if GET call failing after server comes up or before it to make sure we hit GET call only after server is ready to serve the request. Check if really 8800 port is open in the container. Hopefully after this you will get to know the exact cause.

Comment: Rushikesh - thanks for the pointers , I exec into the pod and do a - netstat -ant | grep 8800 command which does not  return anything, it means nothing is listening on that port, does it mean that app is not starting up fine  or the port is  not open , I am just trying to figure out if there is a  relation there.

Comment: If netstat -ant | grep 8800 doesn't return anything then it means app has not opened or started on 8800 port. As you have mentioned pod keeps restarting, it means app is failing to start without error. See pod logs using kubectl logs <podname>, you may see errors in app startup phase. If your container/app exits with non-zero exit code then pod restarts itself. You can also describe your pod to get more details using kubectl describe pod <podname> command.

Comment: Your pointers helped to fix the issue , thanks , the App was not coming up as it was not able to connect to the redis cache in Azure due to fire wall which was not needed, disabled the fire wall to make it work.